# Rails - Turbolinks renders layouts each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I've been trying to add a panel layout to my application like IM window on Facebook or player panel on Soundcloud, which keeps its containing data unchanched after each page visit or page reload. But seems like Turbolinks won't let me do this, re-rendering that layout each time I visit some page in my app.

I was wondering if there's some way to make a static, independent panel which doesn't react to changing pages in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turbolinks lets you [persist elements across page loads](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#persisting-elements-across-page-loads). To do this you'll need to give the element an ID and the `data-turbolinks-permanent` attribute. e.g.

```
<div id="chat-panel-wrapper" data-turbolinks-permanent>…</div>
```